# Unable to do a remote ejb access from a different host

Tags: glassfish

We are using a servlet to access a remote ejb deployed on a different host and getting the 
exception mentioned in the stacktrace below.

1. The remote access works if the servlet client and the remote ejb war are deployed in different domains and on the same host.
2. Works if they are deployed on the same host and same domain
3. does not work when deployed on two diffrent hosts.
4. Looking at the exception"CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No", we thought it could be security issue.
    But the test ejb application didnt have any security configurations. Tried adding the "" details to the sun-ejb-jar.xml
    and used ProgrammaticLogin api. We got the same exception. Not sure if the security config was correct though.
5. The glassfish-corba log level was set to finest in the server where the ejb application was deployed. We then got this exception, "
   org.omg.CORBA.BAD_INV_ORDER: FINE: IOP01600015: Service context add failed in portable interceptor because a service context with id 15 already exists  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 15  completed: No".
   The full stacktrace is mentioned below in the server log.
6. tried using the front-end back-end test cases from Glassfish bug: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15523. We are 
   getting the same exception.

Glassfish version: 3.1 build 43

Not sure where we are going wrong. Please help. Thanks.

### Client Side log:

Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=TestService,Remote 3.x interface =com.medallion.test.service.TestService,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=corbaname:iiop:50.57.150.62:3700#TestService,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'corbaname:iiop:50.57.150.62:3700#TestService__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__' [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: FINE: IOP00100009: string_to_object conversion failed due to bad schema specific part in name TestService__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 9  completed: No]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1106)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:776)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:172)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: FINE: IOP00100009: string_to_object conversion failed due to bad schema specific part in name TestService__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 9  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy142.soBadSchemaSpecific(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.resolveCorbaname(INSURLOperationImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.resolveINSURL(INSURLOperationImpl.java:154)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.operate(INSURLOperationImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.string_to_object(ORBImpl.java:976)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:171)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecServerRequestInterceptor.handle_null_service_context(SecServerRequestInterceptor.java:421)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecServerRequestInterceptor.receive_request(SecServerRequestInterceptor.java:443)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.InterceptorInvoker.invokeServerInterceptorIntermediatePoint(InterceptorInvoker.java:612)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.invokeServerPIIntermediatePoint(PIHandlerImpl.java:612)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.getServantWithPI(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(MessageBase.java:900)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_2.getSystemException(ReplyMessage_1_2.java:131)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:499)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.is_a(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:395)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:112)
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(NamingContextExtHelper.java:73)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.resolveCorbaname(INSURLOperationImpl.java:212)
    ... 47 more

### Server Side log( after setting the corba log level to finest):

[#|2011-12-02T11:37:16.111-0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl|_ThreadID=161;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory;MethodName=setAcceptedSocketOptions;|setAcceptedSocketOptions: SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl[3700 IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT true true] ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=3700] Socket[addr=/173.13.42.205,port=54829,localport=3700]|#]

[#|2011-12-02T11:37:16.113-0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba|_ThreadID=15;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.logging.LogDomains$1;MethodName=getResourceBundle;|Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager|#]

[#|2011-12-02T11:37:16.180-0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba|_ThreadID=161;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.logging.LogDomains$1;MethodName=getResourceBundle;|Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager|#]

[#|2011-12-02T11:37:16.179-0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl|_ThreadID=161;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.POAProtocolMgr;MethodName=getEjbDescriptor;|POAProtocolMgr.getEjbDescriptor->: [B@77dc7838|#]

[#|2011-12-02T11:37:16.181-0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba|_ThreadID=161;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.logging.LogDomains$1;MethodName=getResourceBundle;|Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager|#]

[#|2011-12-02T11:37:16.181-0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl|_ThreadID=161;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.POAProtocolMgr;MethodName=getEjbDescriptor;|POAProtocolMgr.getEjbDescriptor: [B@77dc7838: ejbId: 4,294,967,297|#]

[#|2011-12-02T11:37:16.181-0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba|_ThreadID=161;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.logging.LogDomains$1;MethodName=getResourceBundle;|Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager|#]

[#|2011-12-02T11:37:16.181-0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl|_ThreadID=161;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.POAProtocolMgr;MethodName=getEjbDescriptor;|POAProtocolMgr.getEjbDescriptor<-: [B@77dc7838: null|#]

[#|2011-12-02T11:37:16.183-0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.OMG|_ThreadID=161;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator;MethodName=handleFullLogging;|IOP01600015: Service context add failed in portable interceptor because a service context with id 15 already exists
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_INV_ORDER: FINE: IOP01600015: Service context add failed in portable interceptor because a service context with id 15 already exists  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 15  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor729.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy210.serviceContextAddFailed(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.ServerRequestInfoImpl.enqueue(ServerRequestInfoImpl.java:702)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.ServerRequestInfoImpl.add_reply_service_context(ServerRequestInfoImpl.java:482)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.ServerRequestInfoImpl.setCurrentExecutionPoint(ServerRequestInfoImpl.java:738)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.invokeServerPIEndingPoint(PIHandlerImpl.java:632)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.runInterceptors(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2189)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.createResponseHelper(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2101)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.createResponseHelper(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2089)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.createSystemExceptionResponse(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2014)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1796)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1758)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:255)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
|#]

### Code used:

Client:

### servlet:

@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
@EJB(name = "TestService")
private TestService testService;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter w = response.getWriter();

    try {
        w.write("Test o/p: " + testService.testEJB("This is a test msg") + "\n");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(w);
    }

}
```

}

### sun-web.xml:

```
<ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>TestService</ejb-ref-name>
    <!-- <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:localhost:3700#TestService</jndi-name> -->
    <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:<ip>:3700#TestService</jndi-name>
</ejb-ref>
```

### Remote ejb:

@Stateless(mappedName="TestService")
public class TestServiceImpl implements Serializable,  TestService {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestServiceImpl.class.getName());

@Resource EJBContext ejbContext;

@Override
public String testEJB(String testStr) {

    String userName = ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();

    System.out.println("Username: " + userName);

    return "Msg Recieved: " + testStr;

}
```

### sun-ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 EJB 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-ejb-jar_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-ejb-jar>
<enterprise-beans>
    <ejb>
        <ejb-name>TestServiceImpl</ejb-name>
        <jndi-name>TestService</jndi-name>
        <!--<ior-security-config>
            <as-context>
                <auth-method>USERNAME_PASSWORD</auth-method>
                <realm>database-realm</realm>
                <required>true</required>
            </as-context>
            <sas-context>
                <caller-propagation>supported</caller-propagation>
            </sas-context>
            <transport-config>
                <establish-trust-in-client>supported</establish-trust-in-client>
            </transport-config>
        </ior-security-config>-->
    </ejb>
</enterprise-beans>
<security-role-mapping>
</security-role-mapping>
  </sun-ejb-jar>
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not the answer to your question but I'll mention this here:

We had a similar problem with glassfish 3.1.2 where the occurring exception mentions `CORBA.NO_PERMISSION` and there is no stacktrace on the server side. Somewhere in the logfile we found the Exception `Invalid iiop-listener orb-listener-1. Lazy-init not supported for SSL iiop-listeners`

This is a bug in glassfish see:

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH_CORBA-13

The glassfish admin interface automatically adds an SSL entry to the configured non SSL iiop-listener, due to this, the exception occures and remoting won't work anymore. As workaround you can remove the SSL-config-entry from the `domain.xml` manually to get remoting work again. But a soon as you open the IOP-Listener section again in the admin interface, the entry will be created again on glassfish restart.